# Detect string in Outlook Attachment filename

Tags: regex, vba, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm trying to detect if there is a specific string in the filename.

For example, an attached file is named `"myimportantplaylist.xlsx"` (file extension does not matter) and my keyword is `playlist` (plus or minus spaces or any combination of the word).

I thought about doing this by regexp. I have the following construct that I was hoping to throw a keyword into.

```
Public Sub AttachmentQuery(ByVal attachment As Outlook.Attachment, _
  ByVal mailItem As Outlook.MailItem, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)

  Dim frm As New Form1()

  If (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(attachment.FileName) = ".xls") Or _
    (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(attachment.FileName) = ".xls") Or _
    (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(attachment.FileName) = ".doc") Or _
    (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(attachment.FileName) = ".docx") Or _
    (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(attachment.FileName) = ".txt") Or _
    (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(attachment.FileName) = ".pdf") Or _
    (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(attachment.FileName) = ".xfdl") Or _
    (System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(attachment.FileName) = "*playlist.*")

Then Cancel=True
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use String.Contains function ([MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

So your section that says

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(attachment.FileName) = "*playlist.*"
```

Could become (in c#)

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(attachment.FileName).Contains("playlist")
```

I also would suggest you make the extension checking a bit more manageable, eg by looking up a 'allowed extensions' table of some sort.